# About 4.3.3 warning when i use UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have spent quite a while on this issue. I haven't found a proper answer.
I upgraded my Xcode to 4.0.2 and sdk to 4.3. When I run my application on Device, 2 warnings appeared:

```
    warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.3 (8J2)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit (file not found).
    warning: Tried to remove a non-existent library: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.3 (8J2)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit
```

I have tried to remove the entire directory of 4.3.3 (8j2) and re-fetched again in Organizer. However it didn't help at all.

I have **IOKit** file under **/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.3 (8J2)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A**, after I copied the IOKit from directory "A" to **IOKit.framework** , the first warning gone, but the 2nd one still remained, and i do not think it is the proper way to solve this issue.
Anyone got any clue?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What iOS version is your device running? Is the debugger actually broken or do you just get a warning?

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for reply. Device is iPhone 3g with 4.3.3. Everything runs smooth in device even running the Camera. Just got 2 warnings, no crash, no leaks. I am just wondering if i can distribute app with these 2 warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the debugger complaining, and unlikely to affect your debugging unless you're working with IOKit directly.

This won't stop the code from working, but I would report a bug to Apple.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this reply. So, basically, it won't stop me distribute my app, right? Thanks.